# how set query handler in aiohttp

Tags: python, http, aiohttp

i have next code:

```
from aiohttp import web

PORT = 8080
HOST = 'localhost'

routes = web.RouteTableDef()


@routes.get('/do_something?from={f}&to={s}')
async def test_get(request):
    return web.json_response({request.match_info['f']: request.match_info['s']})
    #return web.json_response({request.match_info['FROM']: request.match_info['TO']})


def start_app():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes(routes)
    web.run_app(app, port=PORT, host=HOST)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_app()
```

My problem lies in the fact that I can not process a link like:
   http://localhost:8080/get_something?from=20&to=24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe on `/do_something` (`@routes.get('/do_something')`). All query arguments are passed into matched web-handler.